# TSQL - How do I analyse the previous row to establish time lapsed between payments

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I need to analyse customer payment history to establish if they could be deemed as "New", "Current", "Lapsed" or "Deep Lapsed" based on the time lapsed in months between purchases.

I've figured out an approach (below) that seems to work by self joining a cte that has a count of payments for each customer which then calculating the difference in months between each transaction.

But is there a more elegant way to achieve this (using SQL Server 2012)?

```
WITH CTE
     AS (
     SELECT [customerID]
          , [transaction_date]
          , [payment_count]
     FROM [Financial])

     SELECT [cur].[customerID]
          , CASE
                WHEN ABS(DATEDIFF([mm], [cur].[transaction_date], [prv].[transaction_date])) IS NULL
                THEN 'New'
                WHEN ABS(DATEDIFF([mm], [cur].[transaction_date], [prv].[transaction_date])) BETWEEN 0 AND 24
                THEN 'Current'
                WHEN ABS(DATEDIFF([mm], [cur].[transaction_date], [prv].[transaction_date])) BETWEEN 24 AND 36
                THEN 'Lapsed'
                WHEN ABS(DATEDIFF([mm], [cur].[transaction_date], [prv].[transaction_date])) > 36
                THEN 'DeepLapsed'
            END AS [Customer_Status_at_Time_Of_Transaction]
     FROM [CTE] AS [cur]
          LEFT JOIN [CTE] AS [prv] ON [cur].[customerID] = [prv].[customerID]
                                               AND [cur].[payment_count] - 1 = [prv].[payment_count]
     ORDER BY [customerID];
```

Comment: Why are you using a cte to select 3 columns?   Why do you have the dates flipped and then take an ABS?

Comment: Hi Paparazzo, That's great. I didn't realize having the dates as `[prv].[transaction_date], [cur].[transaction_date]` instead would return them as positives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are using SQL-Server 2012 there is the [windowing function `LAG()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) for your rescue:

Try something like this:

```sql
SELECT [customerID]
      , [transaction_date]
      , [payment_count]
      , LAG([transaction_date]) OVER(PARTITION BY customerID ORDER BY transaction_date DESC) AS Last_transaction_date
      --you can use this as parameter too
      , DATEDIFF([mm], LAG([transaction_date]) OVER(PARTITION BY customerID ORDER BY transaction_date DESC), [transaction_date]) AS DifferenceInMonths
 FROM [Financial]
```

Comment: Flip and don't have to ABS

Comment: Thanks Shnugo, I'll try that. In the meantime I've discovered that customers who have made payments this year, are returning with a Lapsed status if their previous payment is more than 24 months ago. So I need to get the logic right. `LAG` will definitely help tho'. Cheers.